# How to return a list of married people using MQL query

Tags: java, freebase, mql

I'm quite new with freebase, and I was wondering if it's possible to use a query to return people who are married. I've looked at alot of the properties I could use in freebase, but they only show how to find people married to a specific person. Rather, I'd want to find people who are married, or have been in a marriage in the past.

Answer (score 0):

After a while playing round with the properties in freebase, I tried adding on the following to my freebase query.

```
"spouse_s": [{
     "spouse": []
}]
```

And it works perfectly, it removes any person who doesn't have a spouse_s property. For example, the MQL query below returns "Jaden Smith" as on of its topics:

```
[{
  "type": "/people/person",
  "limit": 10,
  "name": null,
  "name~=": "Jaden",
  "profession": "actor",
}]
```

However, adding in the spouse_s property removes Jaden from the list of results, as Jaden Smith has never been married.

```
[{
  "type": "/people/person",
  "limit": 10,
  "name": null,
  "name~=": "Jaden",
  "profession": "actor",
  "spouse_s": [{
    "spouse": []
  }]
}]
```